# How to find all column names of a synonym

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I usually find all column names of a table in sql server with the following sql

```
SELECT Upper(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name ='mutable'
```

However, now I want to find all the column names for a synonym. What is a way to do this?

Comment: Why would you call `UPPER` on something before comparing it with a value that contains lower case letters?

Comment: typo on my part. I changed the table name before posting the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO [you shouldn't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for any of this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views). The following will work for a table or a view:

```
SELECT UPPER(name)
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = N'mutable';
```

The following will work for a synonym (a requirement you changed later):

```
SELECT UPPER(name) 
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.synonyms 
    WHERE name = N'mutable'
    AND OBJECT_ID([base_object_name]) = c.[object_id]
  ) AS x;
```

You can also just say:

```
DECLARE @obj INT;

SELECT @obj = OBJECT_ID([base_object_name]) 
  FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = N'mutable';

SELECT UPPER(name) FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = @obj;
```

Comment: sorry, I meant `synonym` not `view`. I've changed the question. The query you provided doesn't work for synonym...

Comment: @Sharma of course my original answer didn't work for a synonym, because you never mentioned synonyms. If you had asked how to do it in SQL Server but really meant Oracle, that probably wouldn't work either.

Comment: What are the limitations of this method?  Will it work if the synonym points to an object in a different database?  How about if it points to an object in a different instance?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sys.synonyms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189458.aspx) to discover the `base_object_name`, and from there use [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) as @Aaron showed:

```
select * from sys.columns where
    object_id = OBJECT_ID((select base_object_name from sys.synonyms
                   where name='mutable'))
```

Comment: this works only with synonyms of local objects. Synonyms of objects in other databases or linked server won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the top zero rows from the synonym into a temp table.  This will create a table with the same column names as the base object.  And then query sys.columns in tempdb:

```
SELECT TOP(0) * INTO #tmpColumns FROM mutable;
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpColumns');
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me, where the synonym pointed to a table on a different SQL Server instance.  I'm impressed.