# How to insert a Pandas Dataframe into a SQL Server synonym table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

### Summary

In SQL Server, synonyms are often used to abstract a remote table into the current database context.  Normal DML operations work just fine on such a construct, but SQL Server does track synonyms as their own object type separately from tables.

I'm attempting to leverage the [pandas `DataFrame#to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method to facilitate loading a synonym, and while it works well when the table is local to the database, it is unable to locate the table via synonym and instead attempts to create a new table coordinating with the DataFrame's structure, which results in an object name collision and undesirable behavior.

Tracking through the source, it looks like pandas leverages the [dialect's has_table method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py#L1187), which in this case tracks to [SQL Alchemy's MSSQL dialect implementation](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L2359), which then queries the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` view](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/information_schema.py#L76) as a way to verify whether the table exists.

Unfortunately, synonym tables don't appear in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views like this.  In [the answer for "How to find all column names of a synonym"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786912/2738164), the answerer provides a technique for establishing a synonym's columns, which may be applicable here.

### The Question

Is there any method available which can optionally skip table existence checks during `DataFrame#to_sql`?  If not, is there any way to force pandas or SQL Alchemy to recognize a synonym?  I couldn't find any similar questions on SO, and neither git had an issue resembling this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've accepted my own answer, but if anyone has a better technique for loading DataFrames to SQL Server synonyms, please post it!

SQL Alchemy on SQL Server doesn't currently support synonym tables, which means that the `DataFrame#to_sql` method cannot insert to them and another technique must be employed.

As of SQL Alchemy 1.2, the [Oracle dialect supports Synonym/DBLINK Reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/12/dialects/oracle.html#synonym-dblink-reflection), but no similar feature is available for SQL Server, even on the [upcoming SQL Alchemy 1.4 release](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html).

---

For those trying to solve this in different ways, if your situation meets the following criteria:

- Your target synonym is already declared in the ORM as a table
- The table's column names match the column names in the DataFrame
- The table's column data types either match the DataFrame or can be casted without error

You can perform the following `bulk_insert_mappings` operation, with `TargetTable` defining your target in the ORM model and `df` defining your DataFrame:

```
db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(
        TargetTable, df.to_dict('records')
)
```

As a bonus, this is substantially faster than the `DataFrame#to_sql` operation as well!